# How many of the following functions from $\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ are injective?

Tags: functions

Here are the functions:
$$\begin{array}{l}{f_{1}(x)=|x|+1} \\ {f_{2}(x)=10^{x}} \\ {f_{3}(x)=x^{3}+7} \\ {f_{4}(x)=(x-5)^{2}} \\ {f_{5}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{x} & {\text { for } x \geq 0} \\ {x-2} & {\text { for } x<0}\end{array}\right.} \\ {f_{6}(x)=2 x^{3}-x^{2}-x}\end{array}$$

I plotted each function to find out which ones are injective. But I will rather use an analytically method. I know one can just use the definition of an injective function. I failed to do this for $f_3$ and $f_6$. I'm not sure why.

I have found out that $f_2,f_3$ and $f_5$ are injective.

Comment: Plotting the graph tends to be a very approximate method...sure it can be suggestive, but it's hardly a proof.  For $f_6$, say, look for critical points.  The existence of a local max or min quickly settles the point.

Comment: For $f_3$, show $x^3+7= y^3+7$ implies $x=y$; for $f_6$, show it has two (even three) zeros.

Comment: @Lulu I'm still not sure how to investigate whether $f_6$ are injective or not.

Comment: A quick way to handle $f_6$ is to solve for roots.  we have $f_6(x)=x\times (2x^2-x-1)$ so the roots are at $-\frac 12,0,1$, whence it is not injective.

Comment: @Lulu Alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1,f_4{\color{white}{,f_5}} \qquad$ No even function, with respect to any vertical line (In this cases $x=0,x=5$), is injective.

$f_2,f_3,f_5 \qquad$ Monotonic functions are always injective.

$f_6{\color{white}{,f_3,f_5}} \qquad$ No function with multiple roots (in this case $f(-\frac{1}{2},0,1)=0$) is injective.